# SignalR: Startup class in different assembly

Tags: c#, signalr

i am writing a self-hosted signalr application.
The host is a windows service.

I want to use as Startup class a class present in an external assembly.

If i write the Startup class inside the assembly of the service, all works right.

If i put the class in another assembly referenced by the service, i can't be able to start up the signalr communications.

I used the OwinStartup attribute with no luck.

Can someone help me with a working example ?

I already read the article at http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection, but still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance,
Giuseppe.

Comment: <add key="owin:appStartup" value="StartupDemo.ProductionStartup, StartupDemo" /> did you confgured like this?

Comment: Hi adt, thanks for reply. I have tried the appsettings key with no luck. The startup class is in an external assembly referenced by the service project. Do you have a working example ? I try with a web site inside VS2012, not deployed in IIS.